# How do I fade in my table after loading its contents?

Tags: jquery, fadein

```
    $('a.loadTable').live('click', function(event)
    {
            $('#myTable').html("");

            // loop over elements to load table:

            $('#myTable').append("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name +"</td></tr>");
```

My jQuery function -- approximately what you see above -- loads a table full of elements using JSON from elements in my database.

But, instead of just having it appear on the page, how could I fade it in or do some other nice effect on the table rather than just display it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a .fadeIn() function in jQuery just for this.

```
$('a.loadTable').live('click', function(event) {
    $('#myTable').html("");
    $('#myTable').hide();

    // loop over elements to load table:

    $('#myTable').append("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name +"</td></tr>");

    $('#myTable').fadein("slow");
}
```

You can read more about .fadeIn()'s parameters, easings and callbacks from [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('a.loadTable').live('click', function(event) {
                    $('#myTable').html("");
                    $('#myTable').append("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name +"</td></tr>").fadeIn(750);
```

just ensure that your items have `display: none` (and/or `Opacity 0.0`)